# What is defaultType: 'iframepanel' in extjs 2?

Tags: extjs2

var tabs = new Ext.TabPanel({
        region:'center',
        activeTab:0,
        id: 'main-column',
        margins: '10 10 10 0',
        enableTabScroll:false,
        resizeTabs:true, 
        minTabWidth: 80,
        defaultType: 'iframepanel',
        defaults:{
           closable:true,
           loadMask:{hideOnReady :false,msg:'Loading...'},
           autoScroll : true,
           autoShow:true
        }
    });

Answer (score 0):

The default xtype of child Components to create in this Container when a child item is specified as a raw configuration object.

Analogous to

```
defaults: {
    xtype: 'iframepanel'
}
```

Read more in the [ExtJS 2 Docs](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-2.3.0/docs/).